# Accessing an OLAP data present in Oracle Cubes using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, oracle, olap, cube

I am a newbie to ORACLE.  I would like to access an OLAP cube in Oracle using C#.  Could you please suggest efficient ways of doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now i found a library provided by Oracle: [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) that *may* help access OLAP data from Oracle Cubes.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle OLAP Option cubes can be accessed via SQL using the OLAP_TABLE function [OLAP_TABLE Syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_app_sqlfunc001.htm#i82152)
This requires detailed knowledge of the cube structure and also the [OLAP DML](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e17122/toc.htm#BEGIN) language used to manage the OLAP cubes.  This system is basically the old [IRI / Oracle Express](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Express)  system and language embedded in the Oracle Database Server.

As it's standard SQL used to extract the data views can be defined to handle the OLAP_TABLE functionality on the server.

The [dbms_aw](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_app_dbms_aw.htm#OLADM946) PLSQL package provides functions and procedures for executing statements and programs withing the OLAP cube. It also provides methods for maintainting and building cubes